# VBA - "Call" cannot find the Sub or Function

Tags: excel, vba

I created the following MACRO:

```
    Sub X()
        Call Y
        Range("A1:M31").Calculate
    End Sub
```

Y is defined as Public in another module:

```
    Public Sub Y()
        Cells(13, 13) = A()
        Cells(14, 13) = B()
    End Sub
```

Y, when invoked (via button or after some events) works perfectly and ivokes A and B, which are other Macros defined in the same module as Y.
However, when I try to invoke it from the other module where X is, I get the compilation error: "Sub or Function not defined".

Where is the problem?

Comment: Should be able to use just the method name with no need for the call keyword.  On a side note y is not a good method name.

Comment: I assume your modules / classes don't have some sort of weird scope modifier on them, right?

Comment: Did you step through to see if it is erroring out when calling Y?  Or is it erroring out when calling A() or B()?

Comment: 2) module do not have any other modifier, just subs and functions

Comment: 3) the error is on the call, in fact the Macro works correctly when invoked from the sheet associated to the module where it is defined

Comment: 4) how do I review my questions?

Comment: @Manu, 4): you should see tag "Edit" under your question.

Comment: Usually there are two reasons for strange "Sub or Function not defined": a) the code which is called by Sub is located not in a "Module", but in "Sheet" and b) the called code is located in (other) .xla module.

Comment: Wow, the problem is the one detected by Juri Ruut: the code is in the "Sheet": how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Put the code residing on "Sheet" to module: Alt-F11 (VBE) -> Right click on your project name -> Insert -> Module. Copy the code from the sheet to module, if needed, Call can be made from the sheet.

Comment: If you have CommandButton1_Click() or similar events defined as the Sub you want to run somewhere else, move the main code into Module as a separate Sub and make a Call. Changing Private Sub into Public doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the code to a separate module and it worked.